# Checking to my proof of $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\dfrac {1} {n^{2}}=0$

Tags: analysis, proof-writing

- $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\dfrac {1} {n^{2}}=0$

My proof. Let $\varepsilon >0$ By the Archimedean property there is a $N$ in $\mathbb{N}$ such that $N\varepsilon >1$. So, for all $n\geq N$,

$\left| \dfrac {1} {n^2}-0\right|=\left| \dfrac {1} {n^2}\right|=\dfrac {1} {n^2}<\dfrac {1} {n}<\dfrac {1} {N}<\varepsilon$.

**Can you check my proof?**

Comment: proof is correct

Comment: $1/n<1/N$ is false for $n=N$. And you said that $n\ge N$, so $n=N$ is possible.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Okey. thanks.

Comment: @anirudhb Thanks.

Comment: actually it is $\frac{1}{n} <=  \frac{1}{N}$

Comment: @anirudhb Yes. You are right.

Comment: Also for $\varepsilon=53$ then $N=1$ and for $n=1$ then $\frac 1{n^2}=\frac 1n$ and you used $<$ too.